# Generate javascript errors on purpose

Tags: javascript, conflict, ads, adsense, banner

I would like to remove some hosting imposed google ads on my phpbb board.

Currently I accomplish this by deleting via javascript all the banners divs when the page is loaded.

But unfortunately in that way advertisements are quickly displayed before disappearing.

Now I am thinking about a different (neater) approach to my problem:

maybe I might write some javascript code which interferes with the one injected by google thus generating the inability to show those annoying divs...

Any idea?

EDIT

I can't edit html and css, I am just allowed to insert any html/javascript/css code in a separate "widget". This is for testing purposes and I have the admin permission to try ...

My current code follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('ad').getElementsByTagName('div')[0].outerHTML='';
document.getElementById('ad2').outerHTML='';
document.getElementById('footer').outerHTML='';
document.getElementById('ad3').getElementsByTagName('a')[1].outerHTML='';
};
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to do this?

Comment: I'd double check that. And triple check it. Then check it again to make sure you're allowed to do that :P

Comment: Triple checked and it is ok

Answer (score 0):

Any error-inducing code will almost certainly interfere with things required by phpBB as well as the ads. Generally the ad code is written to be stand-alone, so it doesn't need any external help (eg. scripts in the `<head>` of the document).

Maybe you could target their parent elements with CSS and just apply `display:none` or something? That would likely be a better solution.

Comment: I am unsure on how to apply display:none in my situation, cause, as you can see from my code, I don't always have divs ids. In this case it is like if you got a fully loaded webpage and you are only able to add some html/css/javasctipt (or everything else).

Comment: Can you link to your site (with the ads showing) so we can try to target things?

Comment: www.dreamincode.net (this or any other google adsense site would be a perfect example)

Comment: I can't see any ads on there :P Maybe you can do something with [detecting node insertion](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-node-insertion) though

Comment: Ah, Chrome blocks them automatically on my work computer heh (no AdBlock installed). You should be able to remove/hide them from the page with `$('script[src*=doubleclick|mediaplex]').parent().remove();` (or `.hide()`)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should be sure you're allowed to remove these ads, doing so without permission could get you into trouble.

Assuming by this point you are allowed to:

Throwing an error will most likely crash your own script which tends to be a terrible idea.

You could:

- Try to look for the script tag with the URL and remove it
- Make css rules to hide the div's before they are even displayed, then removing any code generated by the ads.
- Re-write your javascript so it doens't conflict with the other script.